# Repeater Order by Name in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

how to set a repeater that will order by Name A-Z?

Comment: There is no default functionality, you will have to manually write it.

Answer (score 4):

The repeater will simply enumerate the datasource assigned to it. If you want to order the display of the repeater you need to order the underyling datasource.

```
var orderedByNameList = People.OrderBy(p => p.Name);

rptPeople.DataSource = orderedByNameList;
rptPeople.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the `datasource` Ascending would be the easiest way.